# ASP.NET: How to make a link multiline?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink

I'm wanting to make an address a hyperlink.  It would appear as follows...

```
123 Sesame Street
New York, NY 12345
```

Now I want it to act as one link and still show up in that format.  At the moment I've got it as the same link to two different Labels, but this doesn't seem like the right way to go.  How can I improve my current method? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a page break in between the text

> `<br />`

Comment: Is there a better way I've always been told not to use <br /> ... although I'm not sure exactly why I was told that. Perhaps it was against using multiple <br />'s.

Comment: @daveomcd A br is appropriate in this case and perfectly acceptable. Using multiples is a bad idea if you're just trying to get a bunch of space in your document.

Comment: @daveomcd the anti-<br> sentiment was probably related to differentiating between content and layout markup.  For instance, don't use <table> for layout, it's for defining tabular content.  Similarly, <br> is for defining a line break, not for creating space between content areas.

Comment: Just for the records, if you're using an ASP.NET server control rather than an native html anchor tag this "might" cause ASP.NET to invalidate the request in some specific circumstances e.g. posting back the page with `ValidateRequest` set to true (the default)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use plain html for the link instead of a label server control?

```
<a href=#>123 Sesame Street <br /> New York, NY 12345 </a>
```

That would render on 2 lines as 1 link

Comment: Why couldn't you put that in a `Label`?

Comment: I tried it with just html. The label control may html encode. I guess you can try it and see. OK just tried with a lable control and it does not html encode the br.

Comment: I am certain that Label does not HtmlEncode its text content automatically before rendering.  That would break a lot of (my) code!  Notably, `<br/>` is probably the most common markup I inject into `Label.Text`.